# Why does the "MOV DWORD PTR ds:0xdeadbeef" instruction dereference the 0xdeadbeef address?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

I'm reverse engineering a binary and I'm confused, because my theoretical knowledge is currently clashing with what's actually happening.

I thought that this instruction writes the value 0xdeadbeef into edx:

```
mov edx, DWORD PTR ds:0xdeadbeef
```

And I thought that this instruction dereferences that address 0xdeadbeef and writes whatever DWORD value is stored at that address into edx:

```
mov edx, DWORD PTR ds:[0xdeadbeef]
```

However, in reality, running this instruction:

```
mov edx, DWORD PTR ds:0x804bdf4
```

Results in the value of edx being:

```
edx = 0xb73fc115
```

`0xb73fc115` is the value that's stored at the address `0x804bdf4`:

```
x 0x804bdf4
0x804bdf4 <gContents>: 0xb73fc115
```

So that means that the address was dereferenced, even though the assembly didn't contain any square brackets. I thought thatsquare brackets signified a dereferencing operation. What have I misunderstood?

I'm using GDB

---

Update: I just tested it on radare2, and it shows the instruction in the format that I would expect

```
mov edx, dword [obj.gContents]
```

I also tested it with objdump, and the result was the same as with GDB. I assume it's some sort of syntax I don't currently understand?

Comment: dword ptr: = sq bkts. [. ]  ptr means pointer it dereferences what is in the address 0xdeadbeef and moves it to register. it will mov reg , const for direct write not mov (extend) reg, size ptr addr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default assembler syntax used by IDA ([MASM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference) based) does not use square brackets when the dereference is unambiguous. In your case the second operand is obviously a memory address from which the value is read, and DWORD PTR is another hint that a dereference is taking place. If you prefer to always see square brackets, you can switch to the TASM assembler in *Options > General..., Analysis*.

[image: IDA Options]

Comment: But what about this one: `mov eax,DWORD PTR [rax]`. Why are the brackets not omitted in that example as well? Assuming DWORD PTR tells you a dereference is taking place, it should be unambiguous as well?

Comment: Or is it the `ds:` part that makes it unambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

if the operand has square brackets it is dereference
if the operator is preceded by Size PTR segment: then it is dereference
if the size of source operand is not the same as destination then the moves will need a specific extension
either Zero Extend or Sign Extend

in some cases (IDA mostly) will display

```
.text:00404EB1                 movzx   eax, ds:byte_40523D[eax]
```

which is equivalent to

```
0F B6 80 3D 52 40 00    movzx eax, byte ptr [eax + 0x40523d]
```

in this case eax will hold a switch case and the constant is a jumptable

for direct writes the operation it will be

```
mov reg , const
```

like

```
mov edx,0xdeadbeef with no other decorations added
```

[you may go to this site for assembling and disassembling tests of the following snippet](http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/)

```
mov edx, dword ptr ds:[0xdeadbeef]
movzx edx, word ptr ds:[0xdeadbeef]
movzx edx, byte ptr ds:[0xdeadbeef]
movsx edx, word ptr ds:[0xdeadbeef]
movsx edx, byte ptr ds:[0xdeadbeef]

nop
nop

mov edx, dword ptr ds:0xdeadbeef
movzx edx, word ptr ds:0xdeadbeef
movzx edx, byte ptr ds:0xdeadbeef
movsx edx, word ptr ds:0xdeadbeef
movsx edx, byte ptr ds:0xdeadbeef
```